# Arquivo CSV via FTP automaticamente

Tags: php, csv, ftp

Caros, tenho uma duvida, tenho um script em php que ja cria um arquivo CSV para a própria maquina. Preciso com que esse CSV seja enviado para um FTP automaticamente diariamente, entretanto não estou conseguindo pensar na logica de juntar os dois scripts, tendo em vista que é PHP e teria que ser feito por meio de agendamento de tarefa do windows (talvez). 
Segue codigo para gerar CSV

```
    <?php
require_once ('dbacess.php');
require_once('log2.php');
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

session_start();

    $data = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$data.'.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings

// fetch the data

    if (!isset($_SESSION['campanha'])) {
        $campanha = 1;
        $text = "Campanha invalida!";
        logs($text,"warning");
    }else{
        $campanha = $_SESSION['campanha'];
    }

   $rows = sprintf("select * from ivr_contatos, ivr_campanha,ivr_business where ivr_campanha.id = '%s' and ivr_contatos.campanha = '%s' and ivr_business.idvisita = ivr_contatos.codigo and ivr_contatos.status = 0 and tentativas >= qtdtentativas",
    $campanha,$campanha);
    $linha = Populator::ConsultaDB($rows);

// loop over the rows, outputting them
fputcsv($output,array("CHAMADO","ID VISITA","NOME","TELEFONE","TENTATIVA","DATA"),';');
while ($resultado = pg_fetch_array($linha) ) {
    $chamado = $resultado['numerochamado'];
    $visita = $resultado['idvisita'];
    $nome = $resultado['nome'];
    $telefone = $resultado['telefone'];
    $tentativa = $resultado['tentativas'];
    $lastAttempt = $resultado['atualizado'];
    $dataconvertida = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($lastAttempt));
    $codigo = $resultado['codigo'];

fputcsv($output,array($chamado,$visita,$nome,$telefone,$tentativa,$dataconvertida),';');
}
?>
```

Codigo para acessar o FTP:

```
 <?php
// Configura o tempo limite para ilimitado
set_time_limit(0);

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Parte 1: Configurações do Envio de arquivos via FTP com PHP
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// IP do Servidor FTP
$servidor_ftp = '127.0.0.0';
// Usuário e senha para o servidor FTP
$usuario_ftp = 'ftp_tentativas_qualidade';
$senha_ftp   = 'teste';

// Extensões de arquivos permitidas
$extensoes_autorizadas = array( '.exe', '.jpg', '.mp4', '.mkv', '.txt','.csv' );

// Caminho da pasta FTP
$caminho = 'arquivos/';
$limitar_tamanho = 0;
$sobrescrever = 0;

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Parte 2: Configurações do arquivo
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Verifica se o arquivo não foi enviado. Se não; termina o script.
if ( ! isset( $_FILES['arquivo'] ) ) {
    exit('Nenhum arquivo enviado!');
}

// Aqui o arquivo foi enviado e vamos configurar suas variáveis
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

// Nome do arquivo enviado
$nome_arquivo = $arquivo['name'];

// Tamanho do arquivo enviado
$tamanho_arquivo = $arquivo['size'];

// Nome do arquivo temporário
$arquivo_temp = $arquivo['tmp_name'];

// Extensão do arquivo enviado
$extensao_arquivo = strrchr( $nome_arquivo, '.' );

// O destino para qual o arquivo será enviado
$destino = $caminho . $nome_arquivo;

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 *  Parte 3: Verificações do arquivo enviado
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* 
Se a variável $sobrescrever não estiver configurada, assumimos que não podemos 
sobrescrever o arquivo. Então verificamos se o arquivo existe. Se existir; minamos aqui. 
*/

if ( !$sobrescrever && file_exists( $destino ) ) {
    exit('Arquivo já existe.');
}

/* 
Se a variável $limitar_tamanho tiver valor e o tamanho do arquivo enviado for
maior do que o tamanho limite, terminado aqui.
*/

if ( $limitar_tamanho && $limitar_tamanho < $tamanho_arquivo ) {
    exit('Arquivo muito grande.');
}

/* 
Se as $extensoes_autorizadas não estiverem vazias e a extensão do arquivo não 
estiver entre as extensões autorizadas, terminamos aqui.
*/

if ( ! empty( $extensoes_autorizadas ) && ! in_array( $extensao_arquivo, $extensoes_autorizadas ) ) {
    exit('Tipo de arquivo não permitido.');
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Parte 4: Conexão FTP
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Realiza a conexão
$conexao_ftp = ftp_connect( $servidor_ftp );

// Tenta fazer login
$login_ftp = @ftp_login( $conexao_ftp, $usuario_ftp, $senha_ftp );

// Se não conseguir fazer login, termina aqui
if ( !$login_ftp ) {
    exit('Usuário ou senha FTP incorretos.');
}

// Envia o arquivo
if ( @ftp_put( $conexao_ftp, $destino, $arquivo_temp, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
    // Se for enviado, mostra essa mensagem
    echo 'Arquivo enviado com sucesso!';
} else {
    // Se não for enviado, mostra essa mensagem
    echo 'Erro ao enviar arquivo!';
}

// Fecha a conexão FTP
ftp_close( $conexao_ftp );
```